# Can a class which extends an abstract class be non abstract if it does not implement the methods of the abstract class it extends?

Tags: java, oop

I haven't coded in Java for years now and before too didn't revise this concept properly. Recently, I read somewhere that if a class that implements a abstract class but does not implement a single method from it has to be abstract. Is it true or does it mean something else? I have not tried this out myself because currently my PC is not working and the online compiler is getting stuck on loading. So is it true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any class which is effectively final must have all methods implemented.

Comment: yeah but if there is a class which does not implement any of the methods of an abstract class but extends it should it be declared as abstract?

Comment: The derived class only has to be abstract if the abstract class contained or inherited abtract methods. If all methods are already concrete in the abstract base class, the derived class doesn't have to be abstract.

Comment: Yes but I even tried with a single abstract method present in the base class. Then too the derived class didn't need to be declared abstract and it worked. I made an abstract class with a single abstract method in it. And then the derived class which didn't implement its method didn't need to be declared abstract.

Comment: No. That's impossible. It violates [JLS #8.1.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1).

Comment: My derived class which is not declared as abstract but has a method definition but it does not implement the base abstract class's method but extends it. And the method in base abstract class is an abstract method. Then too how its compiling.
https://ibb.co/vjPYtQM
https://ibb.co/nknzcpf

Comment: Is there anything I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes. Your `IextendAbstractClass` does not extend an abstract class. It proves nothing.

Comment: My mistake. I had a doubt before only because from what I had studied before was different and I because I was revising things from the internet I messed things up. But I still didn't get why they have written in this document https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html that "When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class. However, if it does not, then the subclass must also be declared abstract". That line from "However if it does not".

Comment: Why should the class be only be declared abstract if it does not implement methods from its base abstract class?

Comment: Btw thank you for pointing the mistake

Comment: @user47 'I still didn't get why ...': because it *is* abstract without those method implementations. 'Why should the class be only be declared abstract' ...? Nobody has said that. What you asked about, and what you've been told, is when it *must* be declared abstract. You can declare any class abstract any time you like. No 'only' about it'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an abstract class extend a non abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892735/can-an-abstract-class-extend-a-non-abstract-class)

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne got it

Answer (score 2):

Per the oracle docs [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html#:~:text=An%20abstract%20class%20is%20a,may%20not%20include%20abstract%20methods.&text=When%20an%20abstract%20class%20is,must%20also%20be%20declared%20abstract%20](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html#:%7E:text=An%20abstract%20class%20is%20a,may%20not%20include%20abstract%20methods.&text=When%20an%20abstract%20class%20is,must%20also%20be%20declared%20abstract%20).

"When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class. However, if it does not, then the subclass must also be declared abstract."

if we were to try to do the following:

```
abstract class A {
  abstract void draw();
  abstract void paint();
}

class B extends A {
  public void draw() {
    System.out.print("B implements A draw");
  }

  public void paint() {
    Systemout.print("B implements A paint");

  }
}

class C extends A {
  public void draw() {
    System.out.print("B implements A draw");
  }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();

    b.draw();
    b.paint();
    c.draw();
    c.paint();
  }
}
```

Then we would get the following compiler error `C is not abstract and does not override abstract method paint() in A`

However, if we define C as an abstract class and then create a concrete class `D` that simply extends C as follows:

```
abstract class C extends A {
  public void draw() {
    System.out.print("C implements A draw");
  }
}

class D extends C {
   public void paint() {
      System.out.print("D implements A paint");
   }
}
```

and of course update our main method to where we now instantiate class D instead of C (since we cannot instantiate an abstract class) then we get a successful compile and run time. So then, as an answer, yes, if you have a class that `extends` an abstract class, but does not implement all of the method then it has to be abstract as well. I hope I was able to answer your question; my experience is mostly in .NET and I've grown rather stale in Java

Comment: You have implemented the methods of the abstract class in the example so it was needed. My question was would I need to declare a method abstract even if it does not implement a single method from the abstract class it extends. For eg: if the situation is like this:
abstract class A{ 
abstract void draw(); 
abstract void paint(); 
} 

class B extends A{ 
public void blah(){ 
...
}

So as B is not implementing any method from the abstract class A but extends it. Should it be declared abstract?

Comment: I believe so, as we saw in the first code block; if B is extending A which is abstract and it does not define those methods then it has to be marked abstract. At least from what i can see based on the docs and trying to run the code in an online compiler. Also, as far I recall, the implements keyword is reserved for interfaces rather than abstract classes.

Comment: Ofcourse the 'implement' keyword is for implementing interfaces and not extending abstract classes. I too read the docs. However, I tried it on an online compiler it works. You don't need to declare it abstract if it does not implement any method from the abstract class it extends.

Comment: @user47 That's only true if there are no abstract methods that need implementing. See my comment under your question.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Rules are:

1. If a class contains any abstract methods (either by extending an abstract class or by having abstract methods itself), then it must be declared as abstract.
2. If a class is declared as abstract, then it is considered to be abstract regardless of the fact if it implements all abstract methods or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you can. abstract class A has not any methods,subclass B extends A and not be declared abstract.

```
abstract class A {
//empty
}

class B extends A {
    public void draw() {
        System.out.print("B implements A draw");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: When class A has no methods, it's not an example to answer the question. Please extend your answer with at least one method in your abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Class1 {
    int val = 0;   
    abstract public int doit();
       
    public int done() {
           return val;
    }
}
```

The following will not compile.  All abstract methods must be implemented.

```
class Child1 extends Class1 {
}
```

The following will compile. Inherited abstract methods and those in the subclass do not have to be implemented.

```
abstract class Child2 extends Class1 {
}
```

You can read more about [Abstract classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1) in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: it would not compile right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Do the 'not okay' and 'okay' statements refer to what *follows*? Unclear in your answer.

Comment: It is no clearer than before. Usually code precedes comments on it. You haven't even provided a clarifying colon.